# Handle dynamic missed columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a small doubt in MySQL. While loading data from one table to another table I faced one issue

first table: emp

```
id | name | sal | deptno | loc | referby
 1 | abc  | 100 |     10 | hyd | xyz
 2 | mnc  | 200 |     20 |chen | pqr
```

second table:emprefers

```
id | name | sal | deptno | loc | referby
```

Now I want to load the `emp` table data into the `emprefers` table. I wrote a query like

```
insert into emprefers select * from emp after
```

I ran the query, the data was loaded into the `emprefers` table like below:

```
id | name | sal |deptno | loc  |referby
 1 | abc  | 100 |    10 | hyd  | xyz
 2 | mnc  | 200 |    20 | chen | pqr
```

Now I ran the same query a second time. It has failed. The reason is the name column is deleted from the `emp` table.

I edited the query like:

```
insert into emprefers select id,'null'as name,sal,deptno,loc,referby from emp
```

After I ran the edited query again, now records are loading into the `emprefers` table and the data looks like:

```
id   |     name   |     sal     |deptno        | loc           |referby
 1   |      null  |     100     |10            | hyd           |    xyz
 2   |      null  |     200     |20            |chen           |    pqr
```

Every time before loading the `emprefers` table I truncate the `emprefers` table data. And the `emprefers` table structure never changed.

Again, a third time I ran the same query again. The query has failed, the reason was that  the `sal` and `deptno` columns were missing in the `emp` table.
I don't want to edit the query again, reason is we don't know which columns are/get deleted from the `emp` table. 
This time we want solve the issue.
We want to load the data into the second table if the columns are available in the `emp` table, then load the data - otherwise we need to pass `null` or empty values for those columns.
Please tell me how to write a query to check if a column exist or not, and if it exists to retrieve the same column, otherwise assign `null` values for that column.

Comment: what is the relevance of mysqli? mysql-workbench? and mysql-error-1064?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the existing query and truncating the table, it might be a better idea to make delete the whole table, make a copy of the original `emp` table and then insert the data into it. That way they'll always be the same.

```
DROP TABLE emprefers IF EXISTS
CREATE TABLE emprefers LIKE emp;
INSERT INTO emprefers SELECT * FROM emp
```

Comment: it might not work reason is emp table columns deleted after few day  again add that deleted columns and we want to know which columns deleted for that identification we pass null or empty values for that column.so we do not want  distrube emprefers table structure

Comment: please let me any another solution

Answer (score 0):

This statement will create the table over the fly.

CREATE TABLE databasename.emprefers SELECT * FROM databasename.emp;